# How can I create comment on node insert?

Tags: 8

I try to create comment on node insert using `insert()` hook but it collides with `INSERT INTO {comment_entity_statistics}` sql.

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '53-node-field_support' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {comment_entity_statistics}
```

The code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert().
 */
function notifications_node_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
{
    $timestamp = mt_rand($entity->getCreatedTime(), REQUEST_TIME);
    $stub = array(
        'entity_type' => $entity->getEntityTypeId(),
        'entity_id' => $entity->id(),
        'field_name' => 'field_support',
        'name' => 'devel generate',
        'mail' => 'devel_generate@example.com',
        'timestamp' => $timestamp,
        'subject' => $_POST['field_support_message'],
        'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
        'langcode' => $entity->language()->getId(),
    );
    $comment = \Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment::create($stub);
    $comment->save();
}
```

Comment: it seems to me like you creating a node entity .. not a comment, watch the entity_type

Comment: @rémy, no, this is correct for Comment::baseFieldDefinitions. The issue is with the field_name base field. I am not sure what this is supposed to be or if it is even relevant for creating a comment programmatically.

Comment: ups true, thats the entity where the comment is attached to ...

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're hitting some edge case in \Drupal\comment\CommentStatistics::create(), which is called in comment_entity_insert(). The code assumes that there is no comment yet when that is called. Which is an assumption that you are breaking, probably because your module gets called first.

That's arguably a core bug, you could open a bug report and try to fix it there to do a merge query. That said, as a workaround, make sure that your hook is called later than comment. You will have to implement hook_entity_insert() instead of node as that is apparently called later (by default, hooks are stored by modules by weight, name, so C should be before N).

PS: You should enable verbose error logging and check the full backtrace of that error. That can often help with understanding what's going on.

Comment: Related https://www.drupal.org/node/2318875

Answer (score 0):

Works for me using hook_entity_insert instead of hook_node_insert.